# Ansible task - Evaluate when with or and

Tags: ansible

I have vars like this:

```yaml
   vars:
     src_wls: "{{ source_database.src_wls_password }}"
     src_pwd: "{{ source_database.src_password }}"
     tgt_secondary_servers: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

I want it to run this part if the env is `003` or `004` and the secondary server is like `*app02*`

I've tried a few iterations, but can't get it to work. Thanks for looking.

```yaml
- name: Performing managed server 
  shell: "cd {{ dest }}; {{ dest }}/script_app.sh {{ src_pwd }} {{ src_wls }}"
  when:
    - target_clone == '003' or target_clone == '004' 
    - tgt_secondary_servers | regex_search("*app02")
```

> fatal: [lebapp02]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'tgt_secondary_servers | regex_search("*app02")' failed. The error was: nothing to repeat\n\nThe error appears to be in 'main.yml': line 27, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Performing managed server)\n  ^ here\n"}

expecting it to run on 003 or 004 if server is like *app02

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a start, 2 enhancements that are not the source of your error:

- your first condition can be simplified for performance, readability and scalability by checking for the presence of a value in a list with the `in` test rather than making all tests one after the other.
- you're not using default values in case your vars are undefined which can lead to more errors when running (i.e. `variable xxxx is undefined`)

Your real problem is the second condition which:

- is applying a filter returning a string rather than making a boolean test (e.g. `is <some_test>`, `== 'some_value'`, ...)
- receives as a parameter something that is not a regex (or at least not the one you seem to be looking for)

Since you're just looking for a substring, the most straightforward way is to use `search`.

Here is a fixed version:

```yaml
  when:
    - target_clone | d('') in ['003', '004']
    - tgt_secondary_servers | d('') is search('app02')
```

References:

- [ansible tests](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html)
- [ansible filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html)

Comment: what does the d('')  mean/do ?

Comment: In the ansible filters doc above, at the begenning, click on the 'jinja2 builtin filters' link, seach for the one called 'default' and see the documented alias (i.e. shortcut).